# Non projective hyperbolic compact complex space

Tags: complex-geometry, kobayashi-hyperbolicity

A famous conjecture by Kobayashi (perhaps slightly revisited subsequently) states that every compact hyperbolic Kähler manifold $X$ has ample canonical bundle.

This implies in particular that $X$ is projective (and canonically polarized...).

Here is my innocent-sounding question: **is there any example of hyperbolic compact complex manifold which is not projective nor Kähler? What about if one allows singularities?**

In other words, is the Kähler assumption necessary in the above-mentioned conjecture?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 6):

The non-projective Kahler surfaces are either K3, tori or elliptic surfaces, known to be non-hyperbolic. Non-Kahler surfaces are either elliptic or class VII; the elliptic surfaces are obviously non-hyperbolic. Minimal class VII surfaces with $b_2=0$ are either Hopf (obviously non-hyperbolic) or Inoue, by Bogomolov's theorem; the latter admit a holomorphic foliation with $\Bbb C$-fibers, hence non-hyperbolic. Minimal class VII surfaces with $b_2>0$ are conjecturally all Kato surfaces. The Kato surfaces (by Dlousky's theorem, I think) are obtained as limits of  blown-up Hops surfaces, hence non-hyperbolic. For non-Kato surfaces, nothing is known, but they don't exist at least for $b_2=1$ by Teleman's result. I would expect that they are also non-hyperbolic, even if they exist (though everybody I know believes that non-Kato class VII${}_0$ surfaces don't exist, me included; much evidence supporting this view was collected by Teleman, Dlousky, Oeljeklaus, Toma and others).

Comment: thank you Misha for this insight! so it seems that you think that it is likely that non kähler compact manifolds are all non hyperbolic, right?

Comment: It seems so, yes (in dimension 2)

Comment: For bigger dimension we have no knowledge whatsoever, but all known non-Kahler  examples are non-hyperbolic.